# How can I reactively remove an object from an array which is passed as a prop so that it is reflected in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-7 mx-auto">
                <items :items="{{ $items  }}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

where `$items` is a JSON array of objects pulled from the controller. Now, the `items` component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <item v-for="(item, key) in computedItems" :key="key" :item="item"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

The `computedItems` property looks like:

```
computed: {
    computedItems() {
        // referring to the prop that is passed from the blade file
        let items = this.items;

        if (this.filterOptions.type !== 'Clear') {
            items = items.filter(i => i.status === this.filterOptions.type);
        }

        if (this.searchOptions.query.trim() !== '') {
            items = items.filter(
                i => i.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchOptions.query.toLowerCase()) !== -1
            );
        }

        if (this.sortOptions.type === 'asc') {
            items.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
        } else if (this.sortOptions.type === 'desc') {
            items.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id);
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

In `item` sub-component you have the ability to delete `items` through a method as follows:

```
methods: {
    _delete() {
        const _confirm = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');

        if (!_confirm) {
            return;
        }

        axios.delete(`/items/${this.item.id}`).then(response => {
            this.$eventBus.$emit('deleted', { id: this.item.id })
        });
    }
}
```

The event gets picked up by the parent (`items` component) and is handled:

```
deleted(item) {
    const i = this.items.findIndex(_i => item.id === _i.id);

    this.items.splice(i, 1);
}
```

But for some reason, the DOM is not updating and the `v-for` is still displaying the deleted object, though, if I dump the prop, it shows that it has been amended. My suspicion is that Vue can't tell that the object has been modified because it is part of `props` and not a `data`. I've tried the following:

- Using `Vue.delete` instead of `Array.splice`
- Using `this.$delete` instead of `Array.splice`
- Using `Array.splice` on the computed prop instead of the prop
- Setting watchers
- Expanding the computed properties to accept a getter and setter
- A whole lot of searching on the Vue forums

Now, I understand you can't mutate a prop directly because that's anti-pattern, so I used a computed prop, but still, my changes aren't reflected in the DOM.

So, why is the DOM not updating?

Comment: `(item, key)` is actually `(item, index)`. Have you tried `:key="item.id"` on your `v-for` loop?

Comment: @A1rPun I assumed `key` and `index` were interchangeable in the sense that they mean the same thing. But I'll give it a shot. **Edit:** No change. It still didn't update the DOM.

Comment: Yes they can be named anything. Using index as a `:key` is useful for most `v-for` loops except for [these reasons](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State).

Comment: I really think it comes down to props not being reactive. In that case, what's the alternative? Passing a prop and assigning it to `data`?

Comment: when you do `this.items.splice` is `items` a prop at that point or not?  Because if its the source for the child, that will flow back down to the child whenever it's modified.

Comment: @StevenB. yes. I've tried `splice` on the computed prop too. There are no `data` items in that component. Just `props` or `computed` props.

Comment: You can't splice a computed prop.  You need to change the source data.

Comment: @StevenB. sorry, I misread what you wrote, I've already tried splicing the original prop directly, the DOM didn't update though the array updated.

Comment: The original prop or the original array in `data()`?

Comment: @StevenB. I've not using `data()` just using props. Should I be setting the prop to data and then mutating data like I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59337627/how-can-i-reactively-remove-an-object-from-an-array-which-is-passed-as-a-prop-so?noredirect=1#comment104873469_59337627)?

Comment: Yes, clone the prop to data if you need to mutate it.  Or you might find it would be easier to put the data in the store instead of passing a prop.  I see you're using an event bus as well, which is (generally speaking) maybe not a great pattern.  If you're new to Vue, I suggest learning vuex store soon for state/event management.

Comment: @Dan I'm aware of Vuex, I did intend on using it so I might just take the jump now. Consider posting your comment as a answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as requested and I'll list the key points of the topic:

- [One Way Data Flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow):  No prop mutation.  If there's a prop you need to mutate locally in a component, first clone it to data and mutate the clone.
- Use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) instead of an event bus for state/event management
- Vuex allows for global state which can be mutated via actions, in a controlled fashion, from within a component (or elsewhere).  Data flows down from the store and emits up through mapped/called actions.